# What is the metric definition for talking_about_count under the Page Graph API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-insights

For the talking_about_count figure returned under the Page Graph API (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/page) what is the detailed metric definition for this?

All it says currently under the documentation is "the number of people talking about this Page" but what constitutes someone to be talking about a page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/insights#page_stories

> The number of people sharing stories about your page ('People Talking About This' / PTAT). These stories include liking your Page, posting to your Page's Wall, liking, commenting on or sharing one of your Page posts, answering a Question you posted, RSVPing to one of your events, mentioning your Page, phototagging your Page or checking in at your Place